# How to factor third degree polynomial like this.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring

I have problem with factoring 3rd degree polynomial. 
$$m^3 - 2m + 1$$
I know answer is $(m-1)(m^2+m-1)$ but I'd like to know the way to do it.
Thanks for help.

Comment: Did you try anything?  Certainly your insights will be influence by knowing "the answer", but I'd recommend showing an effort (like what happens if you subtract and add $m^2$).

Comment: If a factor is known, did you try to divide by it?

Comment: Please remember that you can choose an aswer among the given is the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 2):

Using the rational root theorem, you can determine that $1$ is a root of the polynomial. In other words, $m-1\mid m^3-2m+1$. After that, you can use long polynomimal division (or Ruffini's rule) to determine the quotient.

Answer (score 1):

Because $1^3-2\cdot1+1=0$, which by the  Bézout's theorem(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_remainder_theorem) gives the factor $m-1$ and   $$m^3-2m+1=m^3-m^2+m^2-m-m+1=$$
$$=m^2(m-1)+m(m-1)-(m-1)=(m-1)(m^2+m-1).$$

Comment: Please complete you post, or an least post a sufficient answer when you first post. Please refrain from reserving an answer slot, to get the oldest time stamp, with incomplete expressions, and post when you have at least a sufficient answer.

Answer (score 1):

Note that

$$m^3-2m+1=m^3-m-m+1=m(m^2-1)-(m-1)=(m-1)(m(m+1)-1)$$

Answer (score 1):

There was a trick that I once learned (Don't remember what it is called) for a cubic equation that stated that if the sum of the coefficients of the first and third terms is the opposite of the sum of the coefficients of the second and fourth terms, then one of the roots is $1$. If the sums are the same, then one of the roots is $-1$. Since in this case $1 + 0$ is the opposite of $-2 + 1$, one of the roots is $1$. Using synthetic division, we get:

```
  ________________
1 |  1   0   -2  1
  |      1    1 -1
     1   1   -1| 0
```

$(m-1)(m^2+m-1)$

The trinomial cannot be factored further, so we are done.

Comment: Thanks mate. This trick is gonna help me alot :)

Comment: @user519709 If you found this answer helpful, you may want to consider accepting it so that future users who may find this question will easily be able to locate the solution that worked for you. (Click the checkmark below the downvote button of my answer)

Answer (score 0):

completing the quadratic:
$$m^3-2m+1=m^3-m^2+m^2-2m+1=m^2(m-1)+(m-1)^2=(m-1)(m^2+m-1)$$